# BFBC2 On the scoreboard, what are the numbers in white squares?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

On the BFBC2 scoreboard, to the left of some player names there is either a black dash or a number in a white square. What is this for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a player's veteran status, or in other words the number of previous Battlefield games they've played and [linked to their current EA account](http://veteran.battlefield.com/).

[image: Battlefield: Bad Company 2 Scoreboard]

Comment: @slomojo Officially? The best I could come up with is [this changelog](http://blogs.battlefield.ea.com/battlefield_bad_company/archive/2010/06/02/playstation-3-server-and-client-update-rolling-out.aspx). Perhaps you'll agree it's the only number they could be talking about.

Comment: "Fixed veteran rank number not showing up in ingame scoreboard" ... yep, sounds like it. Thanks Lee.